# How do I map a java Map including another Map, as element, into hibernate *.hbm.xml

Tags: java, hibernate

is there possibility to map something like:

```
private Map<Website, Map<String, String>> parameterMaps =
  new HashMap<Website, Map<String, String>>();
```

Where 'Website' is my class having some strings attributes, and inner map should be some website specific url parts. I'd like to map it into *.hbm.xml rather than using annotations, because its habit in my project. I appreciate any useful reference to any manual too. Thanks!

Comment: if you are asking if you can create a Map that contains a Map, then yes you can.

Comment: Manual mapping is a bit oldschool http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en-US/html/tutorial.html#tutorial-associations, better update to pojo+annotations

Comment: Oh sorry I propably asked wrong, question is: "How do I map a java Map into hibernate *.hbm.xml file of class that contains desired Map"